# converting a java.util.stream.Stream<String> into a java.io.Reader

Tags: java, guava

Part of my application is given an InputStream and wants to do some processing on this to produce another InputStream.

```
try (
  final BufferedReader inputReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, UTF_8), BUFFER_SIZE);
  final Stream<String> resultLineStream = inputReader.lines().map(lineProcessor::processLine);
  final InputStream resultStream = new ReaderInputStream(new StringStreamReader(resultLineStream), UTF_8);
) {
  s3Client.putObject(targetBucket, s3File, resultStream, new ObjectMetadata());
} catch (IOException e) {
  throw new RuntimeException("Exception", e);
}
```

I am using the new Java 8 `BufferedReader.lines()` to a Stream onto which I can easily map my processing function.

The only thing still lacking is class StringStreamReader() which is supposed to turn my Stream into a Reader from which Apache commons-io:ReaderInputStream can create an InputStream again. (The detour to readers and back seems reasonable to deal with encodings and line breaks.)

To be very clear, the code above assumes

```
public class StringStreamReader extends Reader {
  public StringStreamReader(Stream<String> stringStream) { ... }

  @Overwrite
  public int read(char cbuf[], int off, int len) throws IOException { ... }

  // possibly overwrite other methods to avoid bad performance or high resource-consumption
}
```

So is there any library that offers such a StringStreamReader class? Or this there another way to write the application code above without implementing a custom Reader or InputStream subclass?

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: I don't understand. You already have strings, why would you need another character encoding?

Comment: This is really not how `java.util.stream.Stream` is intended to be used.

Comment: I agree with Louis, but if you really want to do this, keep in mind that you can get an `Iterator` from any `Stream`, so a library that can create a `Reader` view of an `Iterator` of lines would also work (and would probably be the best way to implement this anyway).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like that:

```
    PipedWriter writer = new PipedWriter();
    PipedReader reader = new PipedReader();
    reader.connect(writer);

    strings.stream().forEach(string -> {
        try {
            writer.write(string);
            writer.write("\n");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
```

But i guess you want some form of lazy processing. Stream api does not really help in that case, you need a dedicated Thread + some buffer to do that.